# ADB content query - Browser

Tags: adb

I am having some slight issue using the query

`adb shell content query --uri content://browser/bookmarks" & "adb shell content query --uri content://browser/searches`

I have played around with the browser and added some bookmarks, but I am receiving nothing in return. Does anyone have encounter any issue using the queries?

Comment: AFAIK, this `browser` content provider is not always utilized by all browsers, maybe AOSP Browser though. What browser are you using?